# Regex get all matches including smaller submatches

Tags: regex, non-greedy

I have following input string

```
Testing <B><I>bold italic</I></B> text.
```

and following regex :

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*</\1>
```

This regex only gives following larger match

```
<B><I>bold italic</I></B>
```

How to use regex to get the smaller match ?

```
<I>bold italic</I>
```

I tried using non-greedy operators, but it didn't worked either.

And Is it possible to get both as match groups using like java or c# match groups or match collections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below regex which uses positive lookbehind,

```
(?<=>)<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>.*<\/\1>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wI6fK3/3)

It looks for the tag which starts just after to the `>` symbol.

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=>)` Positive lookbehind is used here, which sets the matching marker just after tp the `>` symbol.
- `<` Literal `<` symbol.
- `([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*\b[^>]*>)` Captures upto the next `>` symbol.
- `.*` Matches nay character except `\n` zero or more times.
- `<\/\1>` Matches the lietral `</`+first captured group+`>`

Comment: Is it possible to loop through both the matches using single regex? In any programming language.

Comment: yep.Most of the programming languages supports lookbehind. In java, you need to escape the backslash one more time because the pattern is surrounded by double quotes instead of forward slash.

Comment: I tried to get all matches in c# and it returened only smaller one. Is is possible to get both matches one by one ? If you can show me java/C# code, it would be great.

Comment: post the input in this link http://regex101.com/r/wI6fK3/3 and save the regex. Then post back the link here. After that, explain what do you want to match on that input. Then i'll show you the c# code.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know, many people prefer using a DOM parser to parse html. But looking at your existing regex, to fix it, I would suggest this:

```
<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^<>]*>[^<]*</\1>
```

See [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/65).

**Explanation**

- Inside the tags, inside of the `.*` that match too many chars, we use `[^<]*`, which matches any chars that are not an opening tag. That way we won't go into another tag.
- Likewise, I changed your `[^>]*` to `[^<>]*` so we don't start another tag
- I assume you will make this case-insensitive

Comment: FYI, added demo and explanation. :)

Comment: thanks , it's working .

Btw, I am not doing this to parse HTML, I am doing it just to learn regex.